# Create and insert table

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I made a table for database and the table created but the insert vales are not working.

This is the table

```
Create table patient (
Patient_ID Number(9) primary key,
First_name varchar2(15),
Last_name varchar2(10),
Contact number(10),
City varchar2(20),
Doctor_ID Number(9) references Doctor(Doctor_ID));
```

This is the insert statement

```
insert into patient values ('21345', 'John', 'Smith', '111-111-1111', 'NJ');   
insert into patient values ('21346', 'Emily', 'Rose', '222-222-2222', 'LA');  
insert into patient values ('21347', 'Mark', 'Cruise', '333-333-3333', 'NY');
insert into patient values ('21348', 'Bran', 'Stark', '444-444-4444', 'TX');    
insert into patient values ('21349', 'Hailey', 'Wraith', '555-555-5555', 'AZ');
```

I am getting an error saying not enough values.

Answer (score 1):

You are only inserting 5 values when your table is expecting 6 (ParentID, First Name, Last Name, Contact, City and Doctor ID)

You need to pass in a value for Doctor_ID

Comment: insert into doctor (Doctor_ID )values ('30114', 'Mark', 'Miller', 'Therapist');

Comment: throw that in along qith patient values?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the table column names during the insert so it tries to add all the data your passing to each column in the table. This is a better way of entering your data when it doesn't require you to insert into all table columns.

```
Insert into `patient` (`table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`, `table5`) values ('21345', 'John', 'Smith', '111-111-1111', 'NJ');
```

To break down your issue more, you have 6 columns in your table, but the data your passing is 5, it will give you this error because 5 is less than 6. If you don't want to receive this error you need to state each column you are entering into as seen above -- BUT that field will need to be a nullable field.

In this case Doctor_ID is missing

```
Insert into `patient` (`table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`, `table5`, `table6` ) values ('21345', 'John', 'Smith', '111-111-1111', 'NJ', 'DOCTOR_ID_DATA_HERE');
```

ANSWER:

```
Insert into `patient` (`Patient_ID`, `First_name`, `Last_name`, `Contact`, `City`, `Doctor_ID`) values ('2125', 'John', 'Doe', '111-111-1111', 'LA', '30114');
```

DOCTOR 30114 needs to already exist because you are referencing from another table, please take note!

Comment: insert into doctor (Doctor_ID )values ('30114', 'Mark', 'Miller', 'Therapist');

Comment: insert into patient ('Doctor', 'Patient', 'Appointment', 'Payment', 'Insurance', 'Bill') values ('21345', 'John', 'Smith', '111-111-1111', 'NJ', '30114');

Comment: So, like the  2nd insert value?

Comment: but I tried to run it and it gave me an error saying missing SELECT keyword

Comment: i've edited my answer try and run the last statement @Clark

Comment: I tried to put it in the single quote and it gave me the same error saying missing SELECT keyword and when I tried to run it your way it's saying invalid character.

Comment: use the backtick ` not single quote ', its the key next to number 1 on your keyboard,under esc. 

Have you already created your doctor too? separately from this query

Comment: yes I have created doctor and that one is working and I tried with backtick too and it gave an error saying invalid character

Comment: Just edited again please try, when you copy and paste it replace the table column quotes with ` backtick and values with ' single quote. and let me know

Comment: When answering a question tagged `[oracle]` it is unhelpful to use `[mysql]`syntax. They are two different databases, albeit both owned by the same corporation.

Comment: I tried doing every way, but it's still giving me the same errors